# Data returned from service is not displaying in component in angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a component that calls a service and returns data, as shown. The data is not displaying on the HTML page. What did I miss? `roots` array is coming back as an array of an array, but the data is correct and I believe the HTML is correct also

New to Angular 2 so any help will be greatly appreciated

The root component.

```
export class RootsComponent implements OnInit {
    private baseRootEndpoint: string = 'http://localhost:59534/api/admin';

    private isUploadBtn: boolean = true; 
    private dbops: number = 0;
    private msg: string = '';
    private dataForm: FormGroup;
    private imageData;
    private contentType;
    private fileLength;
    public roots: Root[];
    private isLoading = true;
    @Input() root: Root;

    constructor(private http: Http, private _rootService : RootService,  fb:FormBuilder) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.roots = [];
       this.getRoots();
    }

    //call the service and bring back a list of roots

    getRoots() {
        debugger;
        var me = this;
        this._rootService.get(this.baseRootEndpoint).subscribe(
            data => me.roots.push(JSON.parse(data._body)),
            error => me.msg = error
        );
        this.isLoading = false;
    }
}

//simple service
@Injectable()
export class RootService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }



    get(url: string): Observable<any> {
       debugger;
       return this._http.get(url);

    }
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="header">
            <h4 class="title">&nbsp;&nbsp; Roots</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1" *ngIf="!isLoading">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Root Name</th>
                        <th>Root</th>
                        <th>Definition</th>                        
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr  *ngFor="let root of roots[0]" let id="index">
                        <td>{{root.DescriptiveName}}</td>
                        <td><img src="{{root.Root}}" name="rootImage" /></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your service please ?

Comment: Quick code format and

Comment: This is the service, though i dont believe its the problem, the correct data is returned.import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Root } from '../root';


@Injectable()
export class RootService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) { }



    get(url: string): Observable<any> {
        debugger;
        return this._http.get(url);
       
    }

Comment: Don't add code in comments under your question. Instead use the [edit link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47294640/edit) and update your question and modify / add code as needed. Why? 1) No one can read it as there is no formatting. 2) it makes following the current state of the question difficult.

Comment: thanks, i just posted it with the service

Comment: Can you provide your `JSON` response you get back from server?

Comment: Also please check if there's any error on your console.

Answer (score 0):

So in angular 2/4 we have to work with observables to let the component know it will be changed so in service:

```
roots: Observable<Array<Root>>;
getRoots() {
    debugger;
    var me = this;
    this._rootService.get(this.baseRootEndpoint).subscribe(
        data => me.roots = (JSON.parse(data._body)),
        error => me.msg = error
    );
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
*ngFor="let root of roots | async"
```

This async flag implies we are resolving the observable we have in our observable, if you want to avoid using an async pipe you can subscribe to the variable in your ngOnInit and let it print to a seperate Array

If there is any problem feel free to contact me :) Good luck!

PS: it would help alot if you would show us your JSON output and tell us if the error gets called or not.